# Gikngo Tests hang during goapp tests

Tags: go, google-app-engine-go, ginkgo

I'm trying to use [Gikngo](http://onsi.github.io/ginkgo/) to write some tests for appengine.

My setup for the tests is as follows:

suite_test.go:

```
BeforeSuite() {
  inst, err = aetest.NewInstance(options)
  if err != nil {
    Fail(fmt.Sprintf("%s", err))
  }
}

var(
  req *http.Request
  ctx context.Context
)
BeforeEach() {
  req = inst.NewRequest()
  ctx = appengine.NewContext(req)

  // Clean up local datastore using the context.
}
```

validation_test.go

```
Describe("Some Test", func() {
  It("ValidateFoo", func() {
    // Access ctx here
  })
  ...
  It("ValidateBar", func() {
    // Access ctx here.
  })
})
```

I see our tests consistently hanging with the error of the type:

```
Expected success, but got an error:
    <*url.Error | 0xc8210570b0>: {
        Op: "Post",
        URL: "http://localhost:59072",
        Err: {s: "EOF"},
    }
    Post http://localhost:59072: EOF
```

This seems to indicate that the API server has become inaccessible.  However, the test output does not seem to indicate this.

What are the ways in which we can debug a goapp test?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Ginkgo or Golang had nothing to do with this.  There seems to be some limitation on the number of fields one can read per second from dev_appserver.py.  (I suspect that it might be related to SQLite which is the DB that dev_appserver uses internally).

The following code points out the problem:

```
package preorder

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"

    "google.golang.org/appengine"
    "google.golang.org/appengine/aetest"
    "google.golang.org/appengine/datastore"
)

func TestLoad(t *testing.T) {
    opts := aetest.Options{StronglyConsistentDatastore: true}
    inst, _ := aetest.NewInstance(&opts)
    defer inst.Close()

    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        req, _ := inst.NewRequest("GET", "/", nil)
        ctx := appengine.NewContext(req)

        k := datastore.NewKey(ctx, ENTITY_NAME, "", 12345, nil)
        var entity Entity
        datastore.Get(ctx, k, &entity)
        fmt.Println("Iteration Count: ", i)
        ctx.Done()
    }
}
```

Any help on figuring out how to work around the limit of 240 operations would be appreciated.  One technique I can think of is to artificially inject delays.